# Filtering text files in C#

Tags: c#

How do I just open files with the .txt extension, I want to my program to pop up an error message if the file is not a .txt file I want a code that can modify this code below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
   of.ShowDialog();
   textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
}
```

Can someone help let's say I want to put this loop

```
if fileextension is .txt then 
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
            of.ShowDialog();
            textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
else show error message(like can not open this file)
```

Answer (score 9):

As I understood correctly, you want to see only txt files in your dialog?
If so, use [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx) property.

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
of.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Comment: +1 - If you only want to use text files, only display text files in the dialog.

Comment: @Oded it works but its i want a sitiuation where if i have a doc file its show an error this

Comment: @MildredShimz - The point is that with this, the user will not be able to select a `doc` or `docx` file.

Answer (score 1):

Can use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method for this

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
if(of.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if(Path.GetExtension(of.FileName).Equals("txt",
                             StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                textBox1.Text = of.FileName;
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' does not contain a definition for 'Ok' and no extension method 'Ok' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't allow all extensions if you only allow txt extension.

```
of.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
```

Will make the OpenFileDialog accept only txt extension files.

Comment: You can put the code in the form constructor, or you can set the Filter property at design time. Click the OpenFileDialog component, and go to the properties window, to the property Filter, and set it to "Text Files|*.txt"

Comment: You should see how the file dialog only shows you folders and txt files when you now open it.